# Hölder continuity on Sobolev space $H^1(a,b)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $H^{1}(a, b)=W^{1,2}(a,b)$ be the Sobolev space, that is, the functions $f\in L^2$ such that $f' \in L^2$,  where $f'$ denotes the weak derivative of $f$. This is equivalent to
$$f(x)=c+\int_a^x f'(x) dx $$
for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$, almost everywhere in $(a,b)$.
Prove that if $f \in H^{1}(a, b)$, then
\begin{equation}
|f(t)-f(s)| \leq\left\|f^{\prime}\right\|_{L^{2}(a, b)}|t-s|^{1 / 2},
\end{equation}
that is, $f$ is Hölder continuous. Also show that if $s \in (a, b)$, then
$$
\lim _{t \rightarrow s} \frac{|f(t)-f(s)|}{|t-s|^{1 / 2}}=0 .
$$

I managed to prove the first part, but for the second I'm stuck. I tried using that
$$\lvert f(t)-f(s)\rvert=\left\lvert \int_s^t f'(x) dx\right\rvert \leq \int_s^t \lvert f'(x) \rvert dx \leq (t-s)\operatorname{sup}_{x \in [a,b]}|f'(x)|,$$
but $f' \in L^2$ is not necessarily bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last step, you can use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
\int_s^t |f'(x)|\,dx\le \left(\int_s^t |f'(x)|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}\cdot\left(\int_s^t 1^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}=\left(\int_s^t |f'(x)|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}\cdot|t-s|^{1/2}.
$$
As $s\to t$ the integral on the right-hand side approaches zero, by (absolute) continuity of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Very simple, indeed!